# Until Loop not working as expected

Tags: linux, bash, shell, debian

I'm currently learning Linux and as an homework, we have to create a few basic shell scripts. Nothing especially complicated but this one is giving me headaches. Here's my code :

```
    until [ "$toPrint" == 'fin' ]
    do
    echo "Enter file name to print out :" ; read toPrint
    sh ./afficher.sh "$toPrint"
    done
```

Basically, I have another script called afficher.sh (I'm french so don't mind the french language used) and it reads whatever file name it gets as a parameter. However, the moment I type "fin", everything is supposed to stop except it still tries to print the file called "fin". I read a bit about the until loop on Internet and once it becomes True, it should stop, which is not my case...

Comment: FYI, `==` isn't guaranteed by the POSIX standard to work inside `[ ]`. Use `=` for string comparisons for compatibility with all POSIX shells.

Comment: Look at the order of operations -- you read, then you run the script, then you go back up to the top of the loop and check the exit condition. You're not checking the exit condition between reading the value and running the script, so of course it doesn't exit immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd implement this like so -- with a `while` loop, not an `until` loop, and checking for the exit condition separately and explicitly:

```
while true; do
  echo "Enter file name to print out :" ; read toPrint
  [ "$toPrint" = fin ] && break
  sh ./afficher.sh "$toPrint"
done
```

---

If you really want to use the loop's condition, you can do that:

```
while echo "Enter file name to print out :";
      read toPrint &&
      [ "$toPrint" != fin ]; do
  sh ./afficher.sh "$toPrint"
done
```

...but personally, I'm less fond of this on aesthetic grounds.

Comment: So basically, I gotta test the condition in the loop and use break if true ?

Comment: I wouldn't say "gotta". There are other ways, but this is shortest and simplest.

Comment: I've added an example of one such other (worse) approach.

Comment: You could put the read *and* the test in the condition: `while echo "..."; read toPrint; [ "$toPrint" != fin ]; do ...; done`.

Comment: I made a few cosmetic changes to try to improve the aesthetics :)

Answer (score 1):

You check the condition at the top of the loop, but you enter the value in the middle of the loop.  The next thing you do after reading the value is always pass it to `afficher.sh` and then once that is done you check its value to see if you should stop.  If you don't want to run `afficher.sh` on the `fin` value, you'll need to make sure your control flow allows you to do the comparison before you invoke `afficher.sh`.